# Java Application that recognizes a Java Class

Tags: java, compilation

I need to write a Java application that recognizes a java class and prints out "This is a Java class" If the class has errors or is from another language it prints out 'This is not a Java class"

Please help.

Suggestions and source codes will be much appreciated.

Comment: I tried using the 'if' and 'else' statement but I get stuck in defining a java class properties.

Answer (score 5):

You will probably need a [**context free grammer**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) to **parse the class according to java's rules** and make sure it is indeed a java valid class.

[**JavaCC**](http://javacc.java.net/) is one library that provides this functionality for you.

The part that you are describing is the checking that a program is valid, in theory of compilation - it is the first steps in compiling a program, and also known as its (compiler's) [Front End](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_analysis_%28compilers%29#Front_end). If you want more theoretical knowledge how it is done, you might want to search about:

1. [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)
2. [syntactic analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)
3. semantic analysis

Comment: in essence build a mini compiler. As simple as that

Comment: Or `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac " + filename);` or something...

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way would probably be to use Java Compiler Api and attempt to compile the class at run-time. If compiles then result is success, and if it doesn't it would be hard to determine if that's due error, or because it is from other language.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [`Class.forName("classname")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) to load it. If you get an exception, then it's not a class file.

If it's a very simple application, then maybe you can get the file as a stream. If the first 32-bit data are not `0xCAFEBABE`, then it's not class file. `0xCAFEBABE` is a magic number that in class file definition.